# Unable to access variable within a function

Tags: javascript

Here is the challenge I need help with:

> Create a variable called `myFriend` using one of the variable declarations described above (`var`, `let`, or `const`). Set the variable you created to contain your friend's name. Inside the greetings function, return the string: "Greetings [your-friend's-name].

New to this, but I can't seem to find out where the error is. Probably easy for you guys but, I'll get there.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MgSV.png)

```js
var myFriend = "Sara"

function greetings() {
  let greetings = "greetings, " + myFriend
}

console.log('results: ,'+greetings());
```

Comment: Here's a clue for you, the question asks you to "return the string". Look up the return keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: You don't return anything from `greetings` why do you expect that it should be anything else than `undefined`.

Comment: just a FYI: If you need help with a problem, it's better to describe the issue in the question rather so people can help you more easily. Something like "Help accessing variable" would be better than "I'm new to coding". Good luck!

Comment: write `return greetings` in your function and use `+` to concenate a string with that return from your fucntion in console log.

Comment: @imjared `Unable to access variable within a function` is not really the correct title?  Accessing `myFriend` in the function works perfectly well there.

Comment: Thanks guys you are the best.  Figured it out.  glad to be a part of this community

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statement.

```
return greetings;
```

Comment: great answer. but, Please add some explanation for the OP as well that why he needs to add a return statement.